# Confusion converting from epoch timestamp in Python

Tags: parsing, datetime, python-3.4, epoch

I have the following simple script (using Python 3.4).

```
from dateutil.parser import *
import datetime
d1 = "1490917274299"
d2 = "1490917274"
```

1) When executing `datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(d1)).strftime('%c')`, the following error raises:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(d1)).strftime('%c')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OverflowError: timestamp out of range for platform time_t
```

2) I've read that avoiding milliseconds solves the issue. So I divide `d1/1000` to get `d2` and voilà!

```
>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(d2)).strftime('%c')
'Thu Mar 30 23:41:14 2017'
```

3) However, if I want to use `parse(d2)` I get an error.

```
>>> parse(d2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/dateutil/parser.py", line 1168, in parse
    return DEFAULTPARSER.parse(timestr, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/dateutil/parser.py", line 578, in parse
    if cday > monthrange(cyear, cmonth)[1]:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/calendar.py", line 121, in monthrange
    day1 = weekday(year, month, 1)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/calendar.py", line 113, in weekday
    return datetime.date(year, month, day).weekday()
ValueError: year is out of range
```

4) If you try to `parse(d1)` you also get an error:

```
>>> parse(d1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/dateutil/parser.py", line 1168, in parse
    return DEFAULTPARSER.parse(timestr, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/dateutil/parser.py", line 578, in parse
    if cday > monthrange(cyear, cmonth)[1]:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/calendar.py", line 121, in monthrange
    day1 = weekday(year, month, 1)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/calendar.py", line 113, in weekday
    return datetime.date(year, month, day).weekday()
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
```

5) Finally, if you use `d1` in https://www.epochconverter.com/, you'll correctly get the intended date.

Why is this happening at all? I just wanted a way of checking if a string is a datetime by the use of `parse()` but is not working eventhouhg the epoch string is fine (at least d2).

On the other hand, why is d1 not fine as epoch?

Thanks!

Lucas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>You've probably figured this out by now, but here it goes anyway:</sup>

#### dateutil.parser's `parse` function cannot parse Unix time — [See this somewhat related issue](https://github.com/dateutil/dateutil/issues/23).

So that answers 3 & 4.

Now on to 1 & 2. The reason why you can't parse d1 is because it isn't Unix time. Unix time is defined as the **number of seconds** that have elapsed since 00:00:00 Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), Thursday, 1 January 1970, minus the number of leap seconds that have taken place since then (Thanks Wikipedia!). If you want to include specify milliseconds, add them after the decimal, like this:

```
d1 = "1490917274.299"
```

#### Be sure to use `float` instead of `int` when you are parsing

```
datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(float(d1)).strftime('%c')
```